# Is there a Reduce operator in R whose operation is not binary?

Tags: r, binary, reduce

R has the Reduce function that lets one recursively build an object. The essential arguments of Reduce are a binary function f and a vector x. A binary function takes two arguments of the same type and returns a value of that same type.

It would be useful to have a version of reduce where the function takes objects of different types and whose return value is of one of those two types. Does R have such a function? Below there is a working example.

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:4, B = letters[1:4])

v <- list(LETTERS[1:4], 4:1)

op <- function(df, s) {
  df[[ncol(df)+ 1]] <- s
  df
}

reduce.with.list <- function(x, v, op) {
  recur.op <- function(x, n) {
    x <- op(x, v[[n]])
    if (n == length(v)) return(x)
    recur.op(x, n+1)
  }
  recur.op(x, 1)
}

reduce.with.list(df, v, op)
```

The result of running this code is:

```
  A B V3 V4
1 1 a  A  4
2 2 b  B  3
3 3 c  C  2
4 4 d  D  1
```

I want to make clear that this is just an example. My objective is not to add columns to a dataframe. The function I am looking for should be able to take a vector of length 1 of type T1, a list of objects of type T2 and an operator op that takes two arguments, one of type T1 and the other of type T2 and return an object of type T1.

Comment: What is the need for `Reduce` here? This can be achieved with `data.frame(df, setNames(v, c('V3', 'V4')))`

Comment: colnames should be improved, but does this go in the direction you're looking for? `v <- list(df, LETTERS[1:4], c(1:4)); Reduce(cbind,v);`

Comment: @RonakShah - No. setNames does not increase the number of columns of a dataframe. The argument dataframe had two columns and the returned dataframe has four columns.

Comment: @Waldi - It works for the specific example I provided, but my question was more general. I want a recursive function that takes 1) an operator with two arguments of different types T1 and T2 and a return value of type T1, 2) vector of length 1 of type T1, and 3) a vector or list of elements of type T2. R has a similar function, Reduce, that applies to the case where T1 and T2 are the same type. Your example worked despite violating this requirement. I suspect this was because R coerced the two vectors to dataframes, but in some cases R would not be able to do the appropriate coercion.

Comment: No, `setNames` does not increase number of columns in the dataframe. It is used to name the list `v`. If you run my code `data.frame(df, setNames(v, c('V3', 'V4')))` it gives output of 4 columns which is same output as you have shown in your post. I don't understand the logic of using `Reduce` here. Maybe this is a bad example or  maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: You are right about your code doing the right thing. Still, it is not an answer to my question, which was more general. I do not want just to add columns to a dataframe, that was just an example. The recursive function should work with all kinds of objects. Take, for example, v <- function() Sys.time(). setNames(v, "V1") returns an error message. However, still in the dataframe case, my modified Reduce would still be able to deal with this v with an appropriate function op that would a) evaluate v and b) replicate the result twelve times, and c) only then apply your technique of setNames.